# How to ensure cargo picks the correct compatible version of a crate when restricting the project's rust version?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo, restriction, rust-crates

I'm setting up a Rust recipe for `bitbake`, which is part of the Yocto project.

My target Yocto uses Rust 1.63, and because I have 1.72 installed on my own PC, I have used `rustup install 1.63.0` to make sure I have the same version as the Yocto toolchain, and then I set this in my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
rust-version = "1.63"
```

However, when I do `cargo add clap -F derive`, it adds version 4.4.4, which brings in `clap_derive/4.4.2`. When I try to build this with `bitbake`, the error is that `clap_derive/4.4.2` requires rustc 1.70.0 or newer:

```
| error: package `clap_derive v4.4.2` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.70.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.63.0
```

I was under the impression that `cargo add` was smart enough to handle this kind of dependency - is that not true? If it cannot, what's the recommended way to find the most recent compatible version of a crate?

Note that `cargo check` manually doesn't throw an error at all - in fact I can manually `cargo build` with 1.63.0 without encountering this error, only the bitbake build reports it, which is a much more controlled and "cleaner" build environment. Could there be some caching with my manual build that is making the build succeed even though the compiler version is too old? Note that I was building manually with 1.72.0 before I added that `rust-version` line to `Cargo.toml`, so maybe that's causing the 1.63 build to succeed, somehow?

Answer (score 1):

`rustup install` doesn't actually switch to that compiler version as default. Try building with `cargo +1.63.0 check`, using `rustup default 1.63`, or creating a `rust-toolchain` file (containing only the string `1.63`). If in doubt, also try removing the `target/` directory, but that's unlikely to be the cause.

Also, the `rust-version` flag specifies a minimum version. As such, `cargo add` is free to ignore it (but I think it also won't respect the `rust-toolchain` file, so it's not smart either).

---

It's possible to get cargo to use an old version of the crate index:

- Rust 1.64 was released on 2022-09-22 (see e.g. the [blog](https://blog.rust-lang.org/)), so 2022-09-21 should do fine.
- The crates.io index is regularly snapshotted and moved to a separate [repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index-archive/branches/stale), we want the branch that points to the next date after that: `snapshot-2022-12-19`
- Get a usable commit hash: `git log -1 --since=2022-09-21 --until=2022-09-22 --format="%H"`: `54ade70850086789af2daa20d67733ce48b1c5a3`
- Fork the repository and update the main branch of your fork: `git push -f https://github.com/davidA/fork-crates.io-index-archive 54ade70850086789af2daa20d67733ce48b1c5a3:main`
- Put the following into your `.cargo/config.toml`

  ```ini
  [source]

  [source.crates-io]
  replace-with = "time-machine"

  [source.time-machine]
  registry = "https://github.com/davidA/fork-crates.io-index-archive"
  ```
- Check that it works

  ```
  $ cargo add clap
     Updating `time-machine` index
       Adding clap v3.2.22 to dependencies.
  ```

Though this does have some downsides, e.g. you won't get later crates that still support 1.63, which might have security implications (`cargo-audit` will still work), and you'll be wrangling gigabyte-sized git repositories a lot...

Comment: Thank you, defining a `rust-toolchain` (or using `+1.63.0`) does a lot of what I'm expecting, although `cargo update` and `cargo add` don't seem to resolve versions based on this. I think I'll need to bisect the `clap` version until I can find one that works with 1.63.0, but at least your answer helps me test with `cargo check`, and thus without bitbake - thank you.

Comment: This is turning out to be quite difficult, because it's not just `clap` that has the compiler version restriction, but also many of its dependencies, and dependencies of those too. I wondered if it is possible to start from scratch, with 1.63.0 installed, and just `cargo add` from there. However, I tried that and it just picks up the latest `clap` which isn't even compatible with rustc 1.63.0, so it's not really going to work. Looks like `cargo` assumes everyone is on the latest version of Rust.

Comment: It's an open feature request. https://users.rust-lang.org/t/cargo-add-version-suitable-for-my-non-latest-rustc/88916/4 (Though I'm wondering if you couldn't get cargo to use an old version of the crate index. It is a git repository, after all.)

Comment: @davidA 
Turns out you can. See edits.

Comment: (For some reason I can't @ you... weird) That's really neat - thank you. I'll see if it's worth doing over trying to get a newer version of Rust working in Yocto Langdale (there's some kind of conflict between meta-rust and the Poky layer in Langdale that nobody seems to have solved).

Comment: Interestingly, `cargo upgrade` seems to respect the `rust-version`, at least in some cases…

Comment: There are some [changes looming](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2024/02/13/this-development-cycle-in-cargo-1-77.html#rfc-3537-make-cargo-respect-minimum-supported-rust-version-msrv-when-selecting-dependencies) on how `rust-version` is treated.